# Google Play InApp Billing and OrderId

Tags: android, in-app-billing

There are some cases where a user contacts our customer support complaining that they did not get the item that they paid for. They provide the receipt sent by e-mail from Google Play, which contains an 'Order Number', equivalent to the 'OrderId' received by the Google Play server.

However, I am sure that generating a fake receipt e-mail with a fake order number and send it to the customer support is not a hard task.

So my question is: is there a way to query the Google server to determine if a particular Order Number is valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can check order numbers against the records from your Google Wallet merchant account, which can be programmatically downloaded as CSV files from Google Cloud Storage. Check out the "Financial reports" page in the Google Play Developer Console for details on how to access those files. The CSV files are usually updated once per day.